# select department name query pre-requiste

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three tables as shown below :

```
Courses(
    Number: integer, 
    DeptName: string, 
    CourseName: string,
    Classroom: string, 
    Enrollment: integer)

Departments(
    Name: string, 
    ChairmanPID: string)

PreReq(
    Number: integer, 
    DeptName: string, 
    PreReqNumber: integer,
    PreReqDeptName: string)
```

and I have to find **Which departments have courses that have pre-requisites in other departments?**

Comment: how its posible sql-server and mysql? what are you realy using ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Select D.Name,C.CourseName, P.DeptName 
     From Department D
     INNER JOIN Courses C ON C.DeptName=D.DeptName
     INNER JOIN PreReq P ON P.PreReqDeptName=D.DeptName AND P.DeptName <> D.DeptName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.DeptName 
FROM PreReq p 
WHERE p.DeptName <> p.PreReqDeptName
```